# C# Photo Frame on Webcam winform

Tags: c#, winforms, webcam, photo

I'm developing a Winform application using `c#` to have something like photo kiosk that we can see in shopping mall.

I managed to find ways to capture image from webcam and store the captured image using easywebcam component. However, I want to have a photo frame around the webcam streaming video hence when the image is captured, the photo frame is included as well.

I have done research for days but still can't get any idea for this. Can any guru enlighten me for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used AForge library for working with web cam from C# and I've liked how clean it's API is.
Here the samples how to add timestamp to video, take snapshot, etc:
http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/samples/video.html

If I understand correctly, you need to have original frame when taking snapshot, so you make a copy of it before painting on frame:

```
Image lastUneditedFrame;

private void VideoSourcePlayer_NewFrame(object sender, ref Bitmap image)
    {
        if (lastUneditedFrame != null) 
        {
             lastUneditedFrame.Dispose();
        }

        lastUneditedFrame = image.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), image.PixelFormat);

        var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);

        // do the drawing of photo frame

        graphics.Dispose();
    }

// on snapshot button click, simply call lastUneditedFrame.Save();
```

Comment: Hi Giedrius, thanks for your info, I read AForge.NET before but I ain't got any idea for photoframe on webcam.

Comment: If I correctly understood the question, I've updated my answer with sample code how that would look like in AForge.

Comment: Hi Giedrius, well, I haven't tried AForge yet but I want to show a photo frame / templates / background image on top of the live stream from webcam, something like layering. The said frame is something like this: http://www.loonapix.com/framer/

Comment: Hi Girdrius, i think the correct term should be "overlay". I need a photo frame to be overlay on my webcam streaming video, so when capture is happened, the overlay frame & image from webcam will be captured together.

Comment: Not sure what kind of pixel format has image from webcam, if has the right one, then simply use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage.aspx to draw your photoframe on top on AForge's one, if not, it should be somewhere in samples or forums, someone did this before I'm sure :)

Comment: Hi Giedrius, I managed to do it inside the _NewFrame event as what you stated:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply, I tested it with the _NewFrame event that you mentioned and add in the overlay method as below:

```
private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Bitmap img = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();

    // Perform Overlay here
    Graphics camImg = Graphics.FromImage(img);
    Bitmap frame = new Bitmap(@"D:\PriusC1.png");
    camImg.DrawImage(frame, new Point(100, 100));
    camImg.Save();

    pictureBox1.Image = img;
}
```

And it worked like a charm, thank you very much!

Comment: just make sure you're disposing everything, Graphics, Bitmap objects are disposable and should be disposed to avoid memory leaks.